# JS Object to string keeping colons for key/value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

My object looks like this:

```
{4: 2, 6: 1, 3: 2}
```

I want to output a string like this:

4:2,6:1,3:2

I have tried first converting to an array and then using stringify, but that replaces the colon between key and values with a comma.

Comment: Integer keys will be enumerated in ascending order. So, you can't create that string in that specific order

Comment: Order isn't important

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Same concept as Igor's answer, just a bit shorter:

```
const input = {4: 2, 6: 1, 3: 2};
const result = Object.entries(input).map(e => e.join(':')).join(',');
console.log(result);
```

And of course, your original map doesn't preserve ordering, so it's impossible to get it in the output.

Comment: what am I missing with these ones? Input is still an object

Comment: Not sure I understand your question correctly, but I've changed the sample to include capturing the result and displaying it. If that doesn't answer your question, then please explain why you'd want 'input' to change?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this would work.

```js
const input = {4: 2, 6: 1, 3: 2};

const result = Object.entries(input).map(([key, value]) => `${key}:${value}`).join();

console.log(result);
// -> "3:2,4:2,6:1"
```

Please note that key-value order in output is not guaranteed to be the same as in original object.

Answer (score 2):

When you get a string with `JSON.stringify()`, you can then replace characters you don't want:

```js
JSON.stringify({4: 2, 6: 1, 3: 2}).replace(/["{} ]/g, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
const object = {a:2, b:4, c:6, d:8};

let result = "";

const len = Object.keys(object).length;

Object.entries(object).forEach(([key, value], index) => {
 if (index < len - 1){
  result += key + ":" + value + ", ";
 }  else {
  result += key + ":" + value;
 }
});

console.log(result);
```

Edited.

Comment: Why get `Object.keys(object).length` in every loop? If you access the third parameter in the forEach, it will return the entries array and you could just use that length: `([key, value], index, array)` and `index < array.length - 1`. Or you could just assign Object.entries to a variable and use forEach in another line